# Pandas date_range returns no values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am currently facing a problem regarding the pandas date_range. I have 2 dates in datetime64[ns] type. The start date and the end date. I am trying to create a dataframe containing the values of date_range between those 2 dates, as index. However, the dataframe created is empty, even though it is supposed to contain values.

Note that when I copy pasted that code and used it in the english version of the site it worked fine. I am facing challenges with the greek one.

The code I wrote is:

```py
customdatedf = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D'))
```

start and end date are defined from another dataframe like this:

```py
start = df['Date'].iloc[0]
end = df['Date'].iloc[-1]
```

and their values are returned correctly, as it appears in

```py
print(start, end)
```

(Timestamp('2019-07-06 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-06-26 00:00:00'))

This is printed

Expected result is a dataframe having as index the dates between start and end date

Comment: It's because you set it as index, you can try for example: `customdatedf = pd.DataFrame({'Date' :  pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D')})`

Comment: I want it to be an index but you are right. This would normally work. However when I type `print(customdatedf.head(5))` for example, it returns Empty dataframe and on `print(customdatedf.info())` it returns `Range index 0 entries` and `Date 0 non-null datetime64[ns]`

Comment: If you want it to be an index, add column which contains some data, this way your dataframe is printable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you made an mistake with your `start` and `end` variables. Since the start is *after* the end variable, so to fix this turn them around:

```
start = pd.Timestamp('2019-07-06 00:00:00') 
end = pd.Timestamp('2019-06-26 00:00:00')

pd.DataFrame({'Col_dummy':['Dummy']}, index=pd.date_range(end, start, freq='D'))
```

---

```
           Col_dummy
2019-06-26     Dummy
2019-06-27     Dummy
2019-06-28     Dummy
2019-06-29     Dummy
2019-06-30     Dummy
2019-07-01     Dummy
2019-07-02     Dummy
2019-07-03     Dummy
2019-07-04     Dummy
2019-07-05     Dummy
2019-07-06     Dummy
```

**Or** if you only want an `index`:

```
pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(end, start, freq='D'))
```

---

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2019-06-26 00:00:00, 2019-06-27 00:00:00, 2019-06-28 00:00:00, 2019-06-29 00:00:00, 2019-06-30 00:00:00, 2019-07-01 00:00:00, 2019-07-02 00:00:00, 2019-07-03 00:00:00, 2019-07-04 00:00:00, 2019-07-05 00:00:00, 2019-07-06 00:00:00]
```

Comment: Yeah! I was too busy looking around that I didn't notice this... Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change `index` into `data`:

```
customdatedf = pd.DataFrame(data = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D'))
```

Please take note that the column name will take default value of `0`.

Comment: This would normally work. However when I type `print(customdatedf.head(5))` for example, it returns `Empty dataframe` and on `print(customdatedf.info())` it returns `Range index 0 entries` and `0(the column name)  0 non-null datetime64[ns] `

Comment: @Yoi123 It does because your start is after your end. You start at `2019-07-06` and end at `2019-06-26` - maybe revert it :)

Comment: Yeah you are right! I was too busy looking around that I didn't notice this... Thanks!